# How can I have @if inside the value of a CSS property?

Tags: css, if-statement, sass

Is there a way to use Sass’ `@if` statement inside the value part of a property? I.e. make the following code work:

```
@mixin color-transition($color:true, $background:true, $border:true, $duration: 0.2s) {
    transition: 
        @if ($color) {
            color $duration linear,
        }
        @if ($background) {
            background-color $duration linear,
        }
        @if ($border) {
            border-color $duration linear,
        }
    ;
}
```

I can’t move `transition:` inside of the if clause because in that case the last of them would overwirte the former …

Comment: You can interpolate  a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply concatenate the answer and print it afterwards...

```
@mixin color-transition($color:true, $background:true, $border:true, $duration: 0.2s) {
    $transition: ''; 
    @if ($color) {
        $transition: $transition + 'color #{$duration} linear';
    }
    @if ($background) {
        @if ($transition != ''){ $transition: $transition + ','; }
        $transition:  $transition + 'background-color #{$duration} linear';
    }
    @if ($border) {
        @if ($transition != ''){ $transition: $transition + ','; }
        $transition:  $transition + 'border-color #{$duration} linear ';
    }
    transition: unquote($transition);
}
```

But of course, you could just simply do it like this:

```
@mixin color-transition($color:0s, $background:0s, $border:0s){
    transition: color $color linear, background $background linear, border $border linear;
}
```

Which allows you to call them all in one go:

```
@include color-transition(1s,1s,2s);
```

With an output like this:

```
transition: color 1s linear, background 1s linear, border 2s linear;
```

Since the default is 0s, technically you have no transition set for those values, although it might overwrite preset values somewhere else, so I see why it might not be ideal, just an idea.

Comment: Hi, I had to change some things in your syntax to make it work (I edited it in your answer …)

Comment: @Tobi Damn, I tripped up over the difference between `=` and `:` in SASS. Thanks, I'm gonna leave it at your correction :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@mixin color-transition($color:true, $background:true, $border:true, $duration: 0.2s) {
    $transition : '';
    @if ($color) {
        $transition : 'color #{$duration} linear,'
    }
    @if ($background) {
        $transition : '#{$transition} background-color #{$duration} linear,'
    }
    @if ($border) {
        $transition : '#{$transition} border-color #{$duration} linear,'
    }
    @if (str-length($transition) > 0) {
        transition: unquote(str-slice($transition, 1, -2));
    }
}
```

Then you can `@include color-transition()` in any CSS rule.  Tested.

### Edit

Now the property isn't showed if there is no transition, and bugs fixed.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn’t work … the commas to separate the values are missing in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a control directive in the middle of a statement like that.  You have to append a string or list variable inside of your `@if` statements and then write out the finished property at the very end.

Your specific use case would be best solved by passing in a list of the properties you want to modify:

```
@mixin color-transition($duration: 0.2s, $properties...) {
    $collector: ();

    // optional
    @if length($properties) == 0 {
        $properties: color, background-color, border-color;
    }

    @each $p in $properties {
        $collector: append($collector, $p $duration linear, comma);
    }

    transition: $collector;
}
```

Usage:

```
.foo {
  @include color-transition();
}

.bar {
  @include color-transition(0.2s, color);
}

.buzz {
  @include color-transition(0.2s, background-color, border-color);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  transition: color 0.2s linear, background-color 0.2s linear, border-color 0.2s linear;
}

.bar {
  transition: color 0.2s linear;
}

.buzz {
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear, border-color 0.2s linear;
}
```

Variation to allow for optional duration:

```
@mixin color-transition($properties...) {
    // optional
    @if length($properties) == 0 {
        $properties: color, background-color, border-color;
    }

    $duration: 0.2s; // default value

    $collector: ();
    @each $p in $properties {
        @if type-of($p) == number {
            $duration: $p;
        } @else {
            $collector: append($collector, $p $duration linear, comma);
        }
    }

    transition: $collector;
}

.foo {
  @include color-transition(color);
}
```

As a quirky side-effect, you can specify different durations of each property:

```
.bar {
  @include color-transition(color, 0.3, background);
}
```

Comment: Thnaks. But seems a bit like an overkill :-) furthermore I can’t omit the duration, like ` @include color-transition(color);`, can I?

Comment: Unfortunately, no (at least, not without significant modifications).  But the other examples force you to either remember the exact order of your arguments (was it "color, border, background"?  or "color, background, border"?) or to specify exactly which ones you want to modify (`@include color-transition($border: false)`).

Comment: Yes, but `@include color-transition($border: false)` is absolutely fine :-)